# Heroku vs GEP vs Openshift: проблема выбора хостинга для работы с backend-ом

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, heroku, hosting

### Превью

Недавно появилась задача написать *клиент-серверное* приложение на *Andoid* с использованием *Websockets*. Собственно, сам сервер думаю писать на *Node.js*. На просторах интернета начал искать **бесплатный** хостинг, который будет "дружить" с данным элементом. Большинство обсуждений ссылаются на использование таких платформ - [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com),[Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) и [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com). Понятно, что каждый из них имеет свои **лимиты** на использования. Таким образом, у меня возникает вопрос, какой лучше использовать ресурс при моих условиях, и, **можно ли**.

## Условия работы приложения

- БД находится *на другом сервере*
- на хостинге будет размещаться лишь *node.js server* для работы с удаленной БД и клиентом (выполнять запросы к БД, возвращать результаты в виде Json и передавать их клиенту). Больше никаких сайтов, скриптов и т.д.
- приложение работает на *вебсокетах* (грубо говоря, должно быть *real-time*)
- приложение будет установлено максимум *на 5000 устройств*

### Условия бесплатного использования

Для Heroku - [здесь](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits), дял GEP - [тут](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits), для Openshift - [вот](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html).

### Вопрос

Как видно из описания, приложение будет использоваться *не будет использовать БД* на стороне хостинга, а лишь его *сервер приложений*, который, в свою очередь, не будет загружен разными ресурсами (файлами, скриптами и т.д.).
Скажите пожалуйста, при всем этом, можно ли выбрать один из этих ресурсов для решения данной задачи?

P.S. Если есть еще какие-то предложения или рекомендации, буду рад их услышать. Спасибо.